# Add a horizontal scrollbar to an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollbar

Is there a way to add a horizontal scrollbar to an HTML table? I actually need it to be scrollable both vertically and horizontally depending on how the table grows but I cannot get either scrollbar to appear.

Comment: ... thought about putting the whole table in a div? ... then add scroll to the div?

Comment: Maybe time to change which answer to be the accepted answer?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Did you try CSS `overflow` property?

```
overflow: scroll; /* Scrollbar are always visible */
overflow: auto;   /* Scrollbar is displayed as it's needed */
```

**UPDATE**
As other users are pointing out, **this is not enough** to add the scrollbars.
So please, see and upvote comments and answers below.

Comment: According to my own attempts and everything else I've read on the internet this simply won't work. You can overflow a wrapper element, sure, but not the table itself.

Comment: @bloudermilk You can if you add `display: block`.

Comment: Don't set `display: block` on tables - surprisingly it strips them of their semantics! This harms accessibility and makes life difficult for users of screen readers. See here https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/03/short-note-on-what-css-display-properties-do-to-table-semantics/

Comment: Wow...so I was struggling to display a table in mobile view as it was messing up my whole phone layout. Thank You @CeesTimmerman. It fixed my issue

Answer (score 440):

## First, make a `display: block` of your table

then, set `overflow-x:` to `auto`.

```
table {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Nice and clean. No superfluous formatting.

Here are [more involved examples with scrolling table captions](https://hamwaves.com/tapers/en/index.html#material) from a page on my website.

If an issue is taken about cells not filling the entire table, append the following additional CSS code:

```
table tbody {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This works for me in Chrome, but only after squashing everything together. `white-space: nowrap;` helps immediately see the scrollbar.

Comment: I actually tried this before. The only issue was that the table cells no longer filled the full width of the table.

Comment: As said by others this doesn't work properly: table rows don't fill the table width.

Comment: @collimarco Have you tried by adding `white-space: nowrap;
`?

Comment: @SergeStroobandt no, in my case `white-space: nowrap;` doesn't solve the problem (tested on Firefox). Rows width is less than the table width when there is not enough content (text) to expand the rows.

Comment: @collimarco Adding an equal number of empty cells should help.

Comment: @collimarco I found two solutions. I did this with display: inline-block instead of block, and the table is only as wide as the rows dictate. Another solution was to make the last td element in each row min-width: 100%, which causes the table to always be full page width. In both cases the text doesn't wrap. They both work on firefox.

Comment: @collimarco Note I had to use max-width: 100% for the inline-block option.

Comment: adding this media query handles "table cells no longer filled the full width" issue like in @media (max-width: 767px)

Comment: This works perfectly in datatables, I always use white-space:nowrap because I don't like multi row cells. Overflow:auto is better than scroll because it only shows when is needed!

Comment: I want to add Horizontal Scrollbar to half of the table, basically I want to horizontally scroll only the right columns of my table . How can we implement this?

Comment: Don't set `display: block` on tables - surprisingly it strips them of their semantics! This harms accessibility and makes life difficult for users of screen readers. See here https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/03/short-note-on-what-css-display-properties-do-to-table-semantics/

Comment: If you use <thead></thead>  and the rule 'table tbody, table thead' columns and headers doesnt match. I didn't use the 'display:table' declaration and put column sizes in <th>'s (inside <thead>).

Comment: Cannot use display: table on thead as well. @jlbofh not sure I understood what you did exactly to avoid this?

Comment: what about thead ?

Comment: Using your code, noticing it doesn't work for tables that aren't "too big", thinking to myself "well, I tried", then noticing the second code block with the exact fix. You are a godsend

Comment: I was using display: block solution until i saw that not full width issue . You can add a container element with overflow-x:auto around the table, and it will display a horizontal scroll bar when needed. That solved all problems.

Answer (score 47):

Wrap the table in a DIV, set with the following style:

```
div.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: It seem that the `overflow:auto` here is unecessary.  Do you know of anyway to achieve this without setting the width... that always seems to be the solution in html - hardcode some width or height but that seems to defeat the point of having a layout engine!

Answer (score 41):

This is an improvement of [Serge Stroobandt's](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30423904/revisions) answer and works perfectly. It solves the issue of the table not filling the whole page width if it has less columns.

```
<style> 
 .table_wrapper{
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<div class="table_wrapper">
<table>
...
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: The `white-space: nowrap;` seems to be optional.

Comment: Excellent! Styling the div wrapper instead of the table, solved the issue of the table not filling the whole page width when it has few columns.

Comment: Seems there's no need for `display: block;`

Comment: @BrunoElo for some reason my table won't scroll without display: block

Answer (score 25):

Use the CSS attribute "[overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)" for this.

Short summary:

```
overflow: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;
```

e.g.

```
table {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: link provided is broken

Comment: To quote @WickyNillams from the comment further above:

> Don't set display: block on tables - surprisingly it strips them of their semantics! This harms accessibility and makes life difficult for users of screen readers. See here  
https://www.tpgi.com/short-note-on-what-css-display-properties-do-to-table-semantics/

Answer (score 20):

Edit:  @WickyNilliams has noted that setting display: block on a table body will strip the table of semantics and thus is not a good solution due to accessibility issues.

I had good success with the solution proposed by @Serge Stroobandt, but I encountered the problem @Shevy had with the cells then not filling the full width of the table.  I was able to fix this by adding some styles to the `tbody`.

```
table {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table tbody {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This worked for me in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on Mac.

Comment: Don't set `display: block` on tables - surprisingly it strips them of their semantics! This harms accessibility and makes life difficult for users of screen readers. See here https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/03/short-note-on-what-css-display-properties-do-to-table-semantics/

Comment: Yikes, did NOT know that!  Thanks for the info, @WickyNilliams.

Comment: It's very surprising behavior!

Comment: table tbody styles you apply will make it so that table thead cols have mismatched widths with tbody cols.

Comment: `table tbody{...}` styles don't get applied to my mat-table... Anyone have similar problems?

Comment: @trainoasis I tried with 4 different table styles, that isn't the case for me.

Answer (score 12):

I couldn't get any of the above solutions to work. However, I found a hack:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

/* try removing the "hack" below to see how the table overflows the .body */
.hack1 {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.hack2 {
  display: table-cell;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="hack1">
    <div class="hack2">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>table or other arbitrary content</td>
          <td>that will cause your page to stretch</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>uncontrollably</td>
          <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: None of the above worked for me either, but this did. Nice one, thanks.

Comment: @Gábriel Glad it worked for you. I tried it again just now in Firefox and it doesn't seem to be rendering correctly :-( https://i.imgur.com/BcjSaCV.png Chrome still looks good.

Comment: Strange; I was using it exactly on Firefox and it worked there - although not in this exact setup. I wanted to render a big grid made up of 10 x 10 px divs with collapsed borders and the maxed-out width + the overflow-x: auto seemed to be the key. With those in place, everything looked perfect. Also, I'm not using <table> at all, only divs, with display: table, table-row and table-cell.

Answer (score 9):

I was running into the same issue. I discovered the following solution, which has only been tested in Chrome v31:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: [`table-layout: fixed` is nice.](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/)

Comment: `tbody {...}` styles don't seem to get applied to my mat-table. Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

Insert the table inside a div, so the table will take full length

HTML

```
<div class="scroll">
 <table>  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.scroll{
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: That worked for me. I usually avoid changing the HTML but in that case it's much easier

Answer (score 5):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%; //width 0, but min-width 100?? yes, I know...
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

`table` can have any `width`. I usually use `100%` or `max-content` for the table.

Comment: This is the only solution here where an explicit width isn't required. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me

```
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper table {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
}

<div class="wrapper">
   <table>...</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out this answer based on [previous solution and it's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423904/8431734) and added some adjustments of my own. This works for me on the responsive table.

```
table {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  // make fixed table width effected by overflow-x
  max-width: 100%;
  // hide all borders that make rows not filled with the table width
  border: 0;
}
// add missing borders
table td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: @Saeed Did you mean something like html structure?

Comment: My bad, I mean add more explanation, to help understand it better

Comment: Hope this version is more clarified.

Answer (score 3):

Seems a bit overdone solutions. Cleanest is to just wrap it with a div like so:

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp

Comment: yes, this is exactly i am using, i was going to add this solution :D

Answer (score 2):

The 'more than 100% width' on the table really made it work for me.

```css
.table-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With bootstrap

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
     ...
   </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the best answer I found was here:
https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw/issues/58#issuecomment-63966574

```
table.tablesaw
{
    table-layout: fixed;
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add tag table to div element with style="overflow-x:auto"

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Name</b></th>
            <th><b>Username</b></th>
            <th><b>Email</b></th>
            <th><b>Avatar</b></th>
            <th><b>Status</b></th>
            <th><b>Action</b></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above solutions but had some issues with them.

If we add `display: 'block'` to the table, the cells do not occupy the full width.
If we add it to the table wrapper, your custom table header like search, filter etc will also scroll which will look bad.

I was able to achieve the expected behaviour by adding `overflow-x: auto` to the body wrapper of the table.

Cells take full width even with less columns and a scroll bar appears automatically as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Like already stated, using `display:block;` on table is bad. I tried most of the answers in this thread, none worked as I wanted. If your HTML is structured like this:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
```

And you want the parent div to be horizontally scrollable, you can try the following:

```css
.text-left {text-align:left;} /* Ignore */

.x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.table {
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.table tbody {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-auto">
  <table class="table text-left">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Head1</th>
        <th>Head2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some short text!</td>
        <td>Some really long text, like really really really really really really really really really really really really long!</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Representation of table

```
<div class="search-table-outter">
    <table class="table table-responsive search-table inner">
    </table>
</div>
```

Css to make Horizontal Dropdown

```
<style>
    .search-table{table-layout: auto; margin:40px auto 0px auto; }
    .search-table, td, th {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
   th{padding:20px 7px; font-size:15px; color:#444;}
   td{padding:5px 10px; height:35px;}
    .search-table-outter { overflow-x: scroll; }
   th, td { min-width: 200px; }
</style>
```

Comment: Indentation and sample data would help if you intend to demo something. Also, did you mean "scrollbar" instead of "Dropdown"?