# Table vertical header?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-table

How can I make the table header appear on the left side of the table as a column instead on the top as a row? I have this markup:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How's this?

#### Example

[image: Example]

#### CSS

```
thead {
  float: left;   
}

thead th {
  display: block;   
}

tbody {
  float: right;   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/TCJjj/).

### Update

> Well, the 1, 2 should also be as column, obviously.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/UbU52/).

It also looks like IE baulks at this. You may have to trade semantic-ness for cross browser compatibility.

### Update

[image: Example]

> If you have multiple rows that you want to become columns.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ltfschoen/jtn6bmyz/5/).

Comment: Well, the 1, 2 should also be as column, obviously.

Comment: @Richard It mustn't of been that obvious then :P. See update.

Comment: Guess where it doesn't work in... IE7. Haven't tested any other versions

Comment: @Gary I had a suspicion it may not. You may have to trade semantics for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Made a minor modification to allow more "rows": http://jsfiddle.net/kwfetzxf/
Also, both seem to work in IE11, Chrome and FF

Comment: Is that possible in some way to have this table to 100% width ?  I wasn't able to do it because of the float I think.

Comment: if you want to display multiple columns of data then you also need to add `tbody tr { display: inline-block; }` as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/ltfschoen/jtn6bmyz/5/. otherwise if you add more <tr>'s in the <tbody> then the data clears to the next row

Answer (score 54):

Just use `<th>` as the first element in the row. Then add the `scope` attribute, which has no visual impact, but you could use it e.g. in CSS.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">A</th>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">C</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See also http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H63

Comment: I agree with this answer. Semantically, "th" is a "table header cell", and you are allowed to use it anywhere as "td" can.

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 2):

You can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ERwAW/). You mean like this?

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th colspan="2">Letters</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Numbers</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You usually use `rowspan` and `colspan` for cells spanning multiple columns/rows.

Comment: I don't want cells spanning multiple columns/rows.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something a little different, but the answers by [@alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5800696) and [@marion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37790154) got me started in the right direction. The problem was that when you needed many items in the table, the "columns" started stacking funny on smaller screens.

Thanks to Serge for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423904) that led me in this solution. This solution allows for scrolling horizontally and doesn't stack funny regardless of the size of the screen/window. I tested it in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge, and IE11. Here's the fiddle with the correct alignment for the new "rows" and "columns": https://jsfiddle.net/berrym/6r3zvaef/21/

And just in case it disappears from JSFiddle:

```
<style>
table{
  display:block;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:100%;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
  width: 10%;
}
thead tr {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}
thead th {
  display: block;
}
tbody {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}
tbody tr {
  display: inline-block;
}
tbody td {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING. THANK YOU. I have been scouring everywhere for this answer -- no one else was taking the stacking on smaller screens into account.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me : (inspired from the first answer)

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MarionLeHerisson/6r3zvaef/)

html :

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a2</td>
      <td>b2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a3</td>
      <td>b3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css :

```
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

thead {
  float: left;   
}
thead th {
  display: block;   
  background: yellow;
}

tbody {
  float: left;   
}
tbody tr {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
tbody td {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: You win the gold star! Thanks for sharing your answer!

Comment: The problem is, that this causes all of the columns to be pushed down below the table when resizing -- do you have a way to counteract that? otherwise this will only work for minimal amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap, you can achieve this easily with the `table-reflow` style: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#reflow

Comment: `.table-reflow` was actually dropped from Bootstrap 4, so this is no longer an option. See [this commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/bd72b9593bbff9a001ba818dbf8782b5ed3f08d0)