# How to make the vertical th's height change corresponding to the change of td?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWqDA/1/), as you can see, `td` at the first line is very long, so that it takes room which is intended for second line. The problem lies in that the `th`'s height doesn't grow large automatically when the corresponding `td` is overwrap to multiple lines.

So is there any way to realize both the multiline showing of `td` part as well as the correct alignment for `th` and `td`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait, can you even put thead somewhere else than on top?

Comment: This accepted answer also does not solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800659/table-vertical-header

Comment: i'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve with this layout since you only really have 1 single column with multiple rows.

if you want to have the height of the row adjust when the content wraps lines, you need to have all of the content in the same row.

while not advised, you can mix `<th>` and `<td>` elements in both the `<thead>` and the `<tbody>`

Without being more specific, we won't be able to advise any better.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, maybe mixing is more feasible. @bdb.jack

Comment: the proper would be http://jsfiddle.net/EWqDA/1/