# Foundation 5 table with horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css, zurb-foundation-5

I was wondering if **Zurb Foundation** has a fix in `table` with many columns. Apparently, 3 to 6 columned `table` will still be responsive... but my table has 12 columns. And I thought that the framework will put the scroll bars to the table.

But my problem is, it does not. So how can **I put horizontal scroll bar to the `table`**? I want to give the table a scroll bar when it reaches the horizontal boundary of its parent (in my case, a `div`):

```
table.oversized { overflow-x: scroll; }
```

But it does not work. I try to put the `scroll bar` instead to the parent `div`:

```
div.parent-of-an-oversize-table { overflow-x: scroll; }
```

And..... it works. But the `width` is longer by ~100px.

Can someone help me with this problem? I'm looking for a solution **within the Zurbs Foundation framework** but if there is another solution outside the framework, is still appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table layout has to have `table-layout: fixed;` -- but according to what I've read you will have a hard time getting a table to take a scrollbar reliably and are better off applying it to the containing div.

For instance, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533636/add-horizontal-scrollbar-to-html-table):

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

gives you a scrollbar in FF and Chrome but no dragger so the scrollbar is useless.

I tried wrapping the table in a div in Foundation 5 using "`large-12 centered columns`" on the div and didn't see the 100px you described. Please include how the containing div was formatted using the F5 grid, since that effects the behavior of children.

Comment: Thanks, getting nearer for what I expected.