# HTML Table Scroll On Phone

Tags: css, html, html-table

I'd like to get my table on my phone to scroll.
I know it is too big to fit - but I'd like to scroll it.

It currently wont.  I've tried `width=100%` no luck...

Seems like a simple request - wondering if viewport has anything to do with it.
I'd prefer to keep the viewport format though - as things display better with it.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=1;">

<table cellpadding=5 border=1 cellspacing=0>
  <tr bgcolor=d7d7d7>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Size</td>
    <td>That</td>
    <td>Weight</td>
    <td>Grade</td>
    <td>Manufacturer</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>KG</td>
    <td>Feet</td>
    <td>Lbs</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Data Location</td>
    <td>More Data</td>
    <td>More Data</td>
    <td>More Data</td>
    <td>More Data</td>
    <td>More Data</td>
    <td>Manufacturer</td>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>More Data</td>
    <td>5555</td>
    <td>6666</td>
    <td>4444</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables look at this. It will help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add horizontal scrollbar to html table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533636/add-horizontal-scrollbar-to-html-table)

Comment: if you use bootstrap you can add the class of table-responsive  which will allow horizontal scrolling of a table that is too wide for the viewport.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wrap the table inside a `div` with `overflow-x:auto`

```html
<div style='overflow-x:auto'>
  <table cellpadding=5 border=1 cellspacing=0>
    <tr bgcolor=d7d7d7>
      <td>Location</td>
      <td>This</td>
      <td>Size</td>
      <td>That</td>
      <td>Weight</td>
      <td>Grade</td>
      <td>Manufacturer</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>This</td>
      <td>KG</td>
      <td>Feet</td>
      <td>Lbs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data Location</td>
      <td>More Data</td>
      <td>More Data</td>
      <td>More Data</td>
      <td>More Data</td>
      <td>More Data</td>
      <td>Manufacturer</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>More Data</td>
      <td>5555</td>
      <td>6666</td>
      <td>4444</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome worked great! Added this to table as well - which tidied things up too: style="white-space: nowrap"

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access the table's parent for any reason (like if you are adding rules to be applied for all tables site-wide), can change the table `display` to `block`.

```css
table {
  display: block;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```