# Table in HTML not displaying as wanted

Tags: html, css, html-table

Trying to create table scrollable.

But it is displaying as: [image].

I wanted as: [image] with scroll.

I tried:

```
<style>
table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead { display: block; }



table.scroll tbody {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

</style>
<script>
// Change the selector if needed
var $table = $('table.scroll'),
    $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
    colWidth;

// Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
    // Get the tbody columns width array
    colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
        return $(this).width();
    }).get();

    // Set the width of thead columns
    $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
        $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
    });    
}).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
</script>
```

I want a table which has scroll effect in it `tbody`

Answer (score 0):

you align everything correctly with forgot to give the width to the main table
which is the reason you did get the required output
Try

```
table.scroll,table{width:100%;}
```

this will give the table a full width and you will get the required output

Comment: Tried, but nothing changed!

Comment: Here is the HTML code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FKWXSM4XT960

Answer (score 0):

Try doing by putting css as below

```
table
{
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Which may work.

Comment: Tried, but nothing changed!

Comment: Or try the below link.It's a duplicate question actually. Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533636/add-horizontal-scrollbar-to-html-table

Comment: I have tried with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody, will then also it can be a duplicate?