# Not able to add Horizontal scroll-bar along with the Table

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am using JSP and Html table tags in my pages and I have scriplets to execute java codes inside my jsp pages.
I dynamically populates the Table data in UI from the DB, based on conditions, and there are almost 15 columns. [in future, more columns to be added]

I want the **Table to be fixed** as per browser's context size and there should be a **Horizontal scroller beneath the table** to scroll the additional columns.

I followed these links:
[Add horizontal scrollbar to html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533636/add-horizontal-scrollbar-to-html-table)

[Table scroll with HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834198/table-scroll-with-html-and-css)

And i used `<div>` to wrap the Table and used below piece of CSS code:

```
div .clsTableDiv
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 110px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Also I tried to put `overflow` style directly to the Table, like:

```
<table class="clsTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" style="overflow-x: scroll; display: block; width: 500px; height: 110px;">
</table>
```

But somehow the scroller isn't working at all. I am not sure if I'm mistaking something or it's the scriplet that I used in JSp to populate data dynamically in the table, is preventing it. Please suggest me on this.

Comment: try to add the same style but to the container div that is wrapping the table, not to table itselft

Comment: can you post your `scriplet` as well because i have tested your code with dummy data it worked well .

Comment: @Kareem Dabbeet, yes I added it to the container div only. It didnot work. Then I added it to table itself. It didn't work either.

Comment: @Swati, the scriplet portion is little heavy, it basically invoking the DAO classes and executing the hibernate sql statements and getting back resutset.

Comment: @Kareem Dabbeet, I verified that the horizontal scroll bar is appearing in Google chrome but somehow it's not appearing in IE11 browser. But we suppose to use ie, not chrome. How can I get that scroller in ie??

Comment: @Swati can u help me out with the above comment??

Comment: Post your related `code` and screenshot of output .