# How to add horizontal scroll on html table

Tags: html, css

I want to add horizontal scroll to my html table. The table width is 100% and the first cell with is fixed to 50 px. You can have hundreds of columns. So i want the first column, with the fixed width to be visible always but the other ones to became horizontally scrollable. All this columns widths need to be sized with the size of the text in the thead.

```
 <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                      <th>xxx</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: Please read also [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an HTML table with a fixed/frozen left column and a scrollable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-a-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-a-scrollable-b)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add horizontal scrollbar to html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533636/add-horizontal-scrollbar-to-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

add this to the table class or id and also give it a specific width so if the cells take more space than the width the scroll will appear.

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

if you want the scroll to be loaded in from the beginning, put this.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

> an example ->

```
<style>
 .scrolltable {
   width: 50px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
</style>

<body>
<div class="scrolltable">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>assssssssssssssssssssss</th>
   <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf</th>
   <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf</th>
   <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>dddddddddddddddd</td>
   <td>wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</td>
   <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf</th>
   <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf</th>
   <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf</th>
   <th>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in a wrapper

```css
.table-wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table-wrapper table td, .table-wrapper table th{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxx</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxx</td>
      <td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```